# Filter BunifuDataGridView with Visual Basic code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filter, datagridview

I am trying to filter the data of a BunifuDataGridView object inside a 
WinForm in VB.NET.

How is this possible?

What is the method that allows filtering the data of a BunifuDataGridView object?

I tried many approaches without success on this. Basically I'm trying to filter a BunifuDataGridView object (I already have the datagrid filled with data) with two BunifuDatepickers (I need values between two dates) but I started from base cases like number conditions or similar to later use it with dates.

```
Dim table As DataTable = TryCast(mainPanel.DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable)
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = "N° = 3"
    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(table)
    mainPanel.DataGridView.DataSource = dv
```

Where mainPanel is a panel inside WinForm. When I try the code above, table is Nothing.

Comment: `DirectCast(mainPanel.DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "ColumnName = Value"`. `Value` needs to be provided in its actual format. E.g., if it's a String, it will enclosed in single quotes: `... = 'Value'` or `... LIKE '%Value%'` or `"ColumnName1 = 'StringValue' AND ColumnName2 = IntValue"` etc.

Comment: @Jimi: I'm getting NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object in that line.
DirectCast(mainPanel.DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "N° = '3'".

Comment: Did you set the DataGridView.DataSource at some point? Is it a DataTable, as in you sample code, or something else? Do you have a Column named `N°` of type String? Any suggestion is as good as the information provided. Have you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I filled the DataGridView from a Dictionary. I have a column named "N°" of type String.

Comment: Why were you tying to cast to a DataTable in the first place, since you used a Dictionary as DataSource? Then, how do you have a Column named `N°` if you're using a Dictionary? The ColumnName and the Column header string (its *description*) are two completely different things. Using a Dictionary, you have `Key` and `Value`. Try to switch to a DataTable as the DataSource, everything is simpler using that kind of source for your data.

Comment: I was filling the DataGridView from a Dictionary directly. I defined a column named "N°". I tried what you suggest me and works perfectly. Thanks a lot. There's any way to clear the filter and get the orgininal data again?

Comment: Sure. Set `.RowFilter = string.Empty`.

Comment: Great! This is perfect. Thanks again. Please answer the question so I can vote it up if you are agree.

Comment: Now I'm trying this:

`Dim iniDate As New DateTime
Dim endDate As New DateTime
iniDate = iniDatePicker.Value.Date
endDate = endDatePicker.Value.Date
DirectCast(DataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DATE>= #" & iniDate & "# and DATE <= #" & endDate & "#"`

This code show the following error:
"System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". I couldn't know why.

Comment: Use the invariant format: `DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "DATE >= #" & iniDatePicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND DATE <= #" & endDatePicker.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"`. The `DATE` Column **must** be of type `Date` (`DateTime`). Note that the upper limit doesn't actually include the day specified, since the `endDatePicker.Value` won't contain Hours/Minutes/Seconds. So maybe add a day yourself, as in `(endDatePicker.Value.AddDays(1)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.